# Is Nvidia drivers updated each Ubuntu version?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I recently installed Ubuntu on my new computer, but I still used my old graphics card.

I installed Ubuntu 16.04, and the version I used before that was 15.10.

But I think the Nvidia drivers from the Settings > Hardware Drivers are the same on both versions of Ubuntu?

Do the drivers not get updated each version of Ubuntu or is it because of my graphics card?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It depends on the card.

Comment: Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers -> give it a minute to refresh then pick a driver ... save and reboot ... ubuntu 16.04 offers very current drivers for Nvidia ( 367.35 )

Comment: That is not true. 367 is only if you use a PPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your graphics card is old, there is a chance Nvidia does not update its drivers any more.  In that case the driver version remains the same.  You can go to http://www.nvidia.com and check what the latest version for your card is and the date it was released.

Running **Additional Drivers** usually shows you the latest driver available for your card in the repos.

Additionally, if you find out that Nvidia has released a later driver than the one in the repos, you can check [here](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) if it exists and install it manually by adding the ppa to your system and following the standard installation procedure.